# How to reference variable in util:RegistrySearch

Tags: wix4

MSI installer needs to install python packages after install the program. So I design the following MSI wix4

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
  <Package Name="log_mask_installer" Manufacturer="BMW" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="a38a6df5-4916-4841-b85c-e2e5b0a55b3a" Scope="perMachine">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
    <Launch Condition="PYEXISTS=true" Message="DLT log mask requires Python 3.11.6, install it firstly, you can download it from: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.6/python-3.11.6-amd64.exe"/>
    <Feature Id="Main">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProdComponents"/>
    </Feature>
      <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="INSTALL_PKGS" After="InstallFinalize" />
          <Custom Action="INSTALL_SVC" After="InstallFinalize" />
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
      <CustomAction Id="INSTALL_PKGS" BinaryRef="PIP" ExeCommand="intall -r [ProgramFiles64Folder]\log_mask\requirements_win32.txt"/>
      <CustomAction Id="INSTALL_SVC" BinaryRef="PY" ExeCommand="[ProgramFiles64Folder]\log_mask\main.py install"/>
  </Package>
    
  <Fragment>
      <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
          <Directory Name="log_mask" Id="TargetDir"></Directory>
      </StandardDirectory>
      <ComponentGroup Id="ProdComponents">
          <?foreach pyfile in Background.wav;config.json;config.py;dlt.py;logger.py;log_watch.py;main.py;requirements_win32.txt;service.py ?>
          <Component Id="$(pyfile)" Directory="TargetDir">
              <File Name="$(pyfile)" Source="pysrc\$(pyfile)"></File>
          </Component>
          <?endforeach?>
      </ComponentGroup>
      <Variable Name="PYPATH" Type="string" Value=""/>
      <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Python\PythonCore\3.11" Value="Version" Result="exists" Variable="PYEXISTS" Id="PY311EXISTS"></util:RegistrySearch>
      <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Python\PythonCore\3.11\InstallPath" Value="(Default)" Result="value" Variable="PYPATH" Id="PY311PATH"></util:RegistrySearch>
      <Binary Id="PIP" SourceFile="PYPATH\Scripts\pip.exe"></Binary>
      <Binary Id="PY" SourceFile="PYPATH\python.exe"></Binary>
  </Fragment> 
</Wix>
```

I tried three different methods to refenrence the variable, it didn't worked.

1. Refenrence Preprocessor variable: $(PYPATH).
2. Refenrence the fragment including variable: [PYPATH].

I'm confused with wix4 variable refenrence.